# Error: clock scan "-100000 minutes" -base 1

Tags: tcl

I just stumbled upon this legacy code, which uses the deprecated clock FreeScan:

```
clock scan "-100000 minutes" -base 1
```

which leads to an error. However,

```
clock scan "-99999 minutes" -base 1
```

seems to work. I would be interested in the reason for this limit, or is this a bug?

Comment: I have to note that changing it to `clock add 1 "-100000 minutes"` works, but the question remains, whether the legacy code shouldnt work as well?

Comment: I think it was meant to be like that, because the error raised from my end is "unable to convert date-time string "-100000 minutes": syntax error (characters 1-6)". Otherwise, I can't seem to find some actual documentation about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a misfeature really, and one that isn't going to be fixed.

The issue is that a six (or more) digit number can be interpreted as either a number or as a timestamp or a time or a date. The parser (something horrible hacked from the output of yacc) gets confused, and when we hit confusion, we spit out an error. Now we could have theoretically fixed it, but this was hardly the worst problem in the parser. (That free text parser is definitely stupid.)

When we worked out just how badly broken it all was, we created the defined-format parser and `clock add` as replacements. They're less magical, and much less wrong.